# How to train XGBoost Classifier with soft output distribution

Tags: python, boosting

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is it possible to train XGBoost Classifier on soft output? Usually, the output of the model is `(N, 1)` in dimension which corresponds to each particular label. In my case however, the label is **soft** for example

```
[0.666, 0.337, 0.000]
```

which corresponds to 3 classes for 1 input. The output of the model when using `model.predict_proba` is already in the above format. So is it possible to train?

I am very new to this model, so please advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Learning Task Parameters* section in [XGBoost Doc](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html), there are various loss functions. Couple of them are `multi:softmax` and `multi:softprob`, which are exactly what you want. Both uses softmax objective function, and according to the documentation, the only difference is their output format while making predictions.

As far as I see, the [python imp.](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L662) already uses `binary:logistic` as its objective function (in version `0.81`) **by default**, and if number of classes is larger than $2$, this objective is automatically converted to `multi:softprob` in any case.

Answer (score 3):

The OP is not asking about the model's outputs, they are asking about how to use non-binary labels as inputs (e.g. with label smoothing), which `multi:softmax` and `multi:softprob` do not support.

For that you have a couple options. You could specify a custom loss function: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html

Or, you can continue using the given multi class objective, create multiple rows for each non-zero class label, and weight them accordingly. As suggested here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432364/training-xgboost-with-soft-labels